# Trouble with advanced netlogo code involving a question mark

Tags: netlogo

I am using Netlogo v6.0.4 and I'm getting the following error message when I try to run sample code from an answer I found here on Stack Overflow.

> Nothing named ? has been defined

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678574/635160) answer the following netlogo code is proposed as an answer:

```
to-report split [ string delim ]
  report reduce [
    ifelse-value (?2 = delim)
      [ lput "" ?1 ]
      [ lput word last ?1 ?2 but-last ?1 ]
  ] fput [""] n-values (length string) [ substring string ? (? + 1) ]
end
```

The specific `?` it does like is the first one in this section `substring string ? (? + 1)` .

When this answer was written in 2014, Netlogo v5 was in active use and it had a feature called `tasks` that were lambda methods. But in [v6 tasks were replaced by anonymous-procedures](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#tasks-replaced-by-anonymous-procedures).

#### Is that what the `?` are here? How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it in one- the `?` in the versions were essentially placeholders for whatever variable was being passed to the task. The [5.3 dictionary entry](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.3.1/docs/dictionary.html#foreach) for `foreach` has a good example:

```
foreach [1.1 2.2 2.6] [ show (word ? " -> " round ?) ]
=> 1.1 -> 1
=> 2.2 -> 2
=> 2.6 -> 3
```

In that case, `foreach` was taking the input list of `[1.1 2.2 2.6]` and iterating over it, where the `?` takes the place in the command block of the current item being processed. As I understand it, the main syntactical difference in 6.X is that now you explicitly state what that placeholder is, by using the `->` operator. So, the exact same idea as above, translated to 6.0 in the `foreach` example in the [6.0 dictionary entry](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/foreach.html), looks like this:

```
foreach [1.1 2.2 2.6] [ x -> show (word x " -> " round x) ]
=> 1.1 -> 1
=> 2.2 -> 2
=> 2.6 -> 3
```

There, you can see that the `x` is explicitly being defined as the placeholder. This really improves the clarity of code- you can define the placeholder however you like to be as clear and explicit as you'd like- this (over the top) example works just as well:

```
foreach [ 1.1 2.2 2.6 ] [ round_me -> show (word round_me " -> " round round_me) ]
```

If you're using multiple lists, do note that you have to surround the anonymous procedure with `( )` and your placeholder declaration with `[ ]`- for example:

```
( foreach [ 1 2 3 ] [ 10 20 30 ] [ [ a b ] -> print a * b ] )
```

If you're translating your code example, then, you can just focus on explicitly stating the placeholders. It also might help to break it down into the component parts to clarify- more detail in comments:

```
to-report split2 [ string delim ]
  ; split the string up into individual characters
  let characters fput [""] n-values ( length string ) [ a -> substring string a ( a + 1 ) ]

  ;  build words, cutting where the delimiter occurs
  let output reduce [ [ b c ] -> 
    ifelse-value ( c = delim ) 
    [ lput "" b ] 
    [ lput word last b c but-last b ]
  ] characters

  report output
end
```

Now, to follow Nicolas' example from your linked answer, you can call that `to-report` to split up your text:

```
to read-example
  let line "Example\tof\tsome\ttext"

  show split2 line "\t"
end
```

Gives you:

```
observer: ["Example" "of" "some" "text"]
```

Hope that is helpful!

Comment: Very nice answer. I cross-linked it from [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678574/487946).